# root password ignored in mysql docker container

Tags: mysql, docker

My docker compose:

```
version: '3.9'

services:

  mysql_db:
    container_name: mysql_db
    image: mysql
    volumes:
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./my.cnf:/etc/my.cnf
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass

volumes:
  mysql_data:
    name: mysql_data
```

The named volume `mysql_data` doesn't exist.

I start the container as root user with `docker compose up -d`.

Upon log inspection I get:

```
root@grafana:~/mysql# docker compose up -d
[+] Running 3/3
 ⠿ Network mysql_default  Created                                                                                           0.1s
 ⠿ Volume "mysql_data"    Created                                                                                           0.0s
 ⠿ Container mysql_db     Started                                                                                           0.7s
root@grafana:~/mysql# docker logs mysql_db
2022-09-16 09:47:19+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.30-1.el8 started.
2022-09-16 09:47:19+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2022-09-16 09:47:19+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.30-1.el8 started.
2022-09-16 09:47:20+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files
2022-09-16T09:47:20.072562Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
2022-09-16T09:47:20.072669Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.30) initializing of server in progress as process 80
2022-09-16T09:47:20.081991Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-09-16T09:47:20.675144Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2022-09-16T09:47:22.257058Z 6 [Warning] [MY-010453] [Server] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.
```

Why empty password ????

Comment: I tried it, and it worked for me with `Docker version 20.10.18, build b40c2f6`.

Comment: you tried as root user ?